# Counting in Hadoop Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to count values similar in a map where key would be the value in the Hive table column and the corresponding value is the count.

For example, for the table below:

```
+-------+-------+
| Col 1 | Col 2 |
+-------+-------+
| Key1  | Val1  |
| Key1  | Val2  |
| Key2  | Val1  |
+-------+-------+
```

So the hive query should return something like

```
Key1=2
Key2=1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a simple group by.

`SELECT Col1, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Col1`

Comment: Is there a way to do a second level of grouping. I am actually getting the above output as a grouped query only.

Comment: You mean group by 2 columns? You can just put multiple columns in the group by.